# Uploading photo to my profile on Facebook, so that nobody notices

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-privacy, facebook-profile

Is it possible to upload a photo to one of my albums on Facebook, so that the news about it will never appear anywhere... Neither in my timeline of my profile nor in the news feed of my friends etc... It will just be in my albums and nobody will learn about it except me since I know I put it in of my albums.
Facebook makes people share everything but what if I don't want to share particular thing with anybody...
I only want to have a photo in my profile, so that friends who come to see my profile will see the photo in there...

Comment: Facebook has had configurable security for at least 4 years now, though the way of setting it up has gotten easier.  Click on the lock-looking icon next to your name for quick access to the settings.

Bear in mind that your profile photo, name, and gender are considered public information and your ability to hide them may be more limited than most other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload the photo, simply change the privacy setting to "Only Me".

[image: screen shot]